# Error when trying call mint (ERC20)

Tags: solidity

I have next construction

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("ACDMToken", "AKDM") {     
    }
}

contract ACDMPlatform {
    address public token;

constructor(address _ACDMToken) {
        token = _ACDMToken;
    }

 function startSaleRound(uint supply) public {
        Token(token)._mint(address(this), supply);
    }
}
```

And error appears when I'm trying to mint, What's the reason?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**_mint** is a function inherited from ERC20 contract. Whereares ACDMPlatform isn't inherit the ERC20 contract, the `_mint()` function is not visibile for it.
To resolve this problem, try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {

    constructor() ERC20("ACDMToken", "AKDM") { 
    }

    function mint(address _from, uint _supply) public {
        _mint(_from, _supply);
    }
}

contract ACDMPlatform {
    address public token;

    constructor(address _ACDMToken) {
        token = _ACDMToken;
    }
    
    function startSaleRound(uint supply) public {
        Token t = new Token();
        t.mint(address(this), supply);
    }

}
```

Comment: What address will "t" have? In this example we don't pass address